# sass - como compilar o arquivo minificado?

Tags: css, sass, preprocessador

Utilizo o sass para ajudar no desenvolvimento, porém gostaria de otimizar o resultado final do css gerado, teria alguma maneira de gerar o arquivo .css já minificado?

Utilizo o seguinte comando para compilar os arquivos .scss

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sass --watch scss:css --style compressed
```